# Teradata SQL Assistant - How can I pivot or transpose large tables with many columns and many rows?

Tags: sql, teradata, transpose

I am using Teradata SQL Assistant Version TD 16.10.06.01 ...

I have seen a lot people transpose data for set smallish tables but I am working on thousands of clients and need the break the columns up into Line Item Values to compare orders/highlight differences between orders. Problem is it is all horizontally linked and I need to transpose it to Id,Transaction id,Version and Line Item Value 1, Line Item Value 2... then another column comparing values to see if they changed.

example:

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
| Id | First Name | Last Name |    DOB     | transaction id |  Make  | Location | Postcode | Year |    Price    |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | John       | Smith     | 15/11/2001 |        1654654 | Audi   | NSW      |     2222 | 2019 | $ 10,000.00 |
|  2 | Mark       | White     | 11/02/2002 |        1661200 | BMW    | WA       |     8888 | 2016 | $ 8,999.00  |
|  3 | Bob        | Grey      | 10/05/2002 |        1667746 | Ford   | QLD      |     9999 | 2013 | $ 3,000.00  |
|  4 | Phil       | Faux      | 6/08/2002  |        1674292 | Holden | SA       |     1111 | 2000 | $ 5,800.00  |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------+
```

hoping to change the data to :

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+---------+-----+
| id | trans_id | Vers_ord | Item Val | Ln_Itm_Dscrptn | Org_Val  | Updt_Val | Amndd_Ord_chck | Lbl_Rnk | ... |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+---------+-----+
|  1 |  1654654 |        2 |    11169 | Make           | Audi BLK | Audi WHT | Yes            |       1 |     |
|  1 |  1654654 |        2 |    11189 | Location       | NSW      | WA       | Yes            |       2 |     |
|  1 |  1654654 |        2 |    23689 | Postcode       | 2222     | 6000     | Yes            |       3 |     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+---------+-----+
```

Recently with smaller data I created a table added in Values then used a case statement when value 1 then xyz with a product join ... and the data warehouse admins didn't mention anything out of order. but I only had row 16 by 200 column table to transpose ( Sum, Avg, Count, Median(function) x 4 subsets of clients) , which were significantly smaller than my current tables to make comparisons with.

I am worried my prior method will probably slow the data Warehouse down, plus take me significant amount of time to type the SQL.

Is there a better way to transpose large tables?

Comment: SQL Assistant is a client (and 14 very outdated), what's the database version you're working with? There's both PIVOT and UNPIVOT in recent releases.

Comment: I don't see what your results have to do with the sample data.  There are no changes shown for the transaction.  There are four transactions in the original data and only one transaction in the results.

Comment: The results are the intended output snippet that I am trying to get to.... there is around 360,000 clients and multiple versions of orders to compare....... I can't remember the Teradata Version only that I have used the Median function which apparently was a new thing for our company.....

Comment: `select InfoData from dbc.dbcinfoV where InfoKey = 'RELEASE';` returns the TD version

Comment: Version TD 16.10.06.01